# How to print line number and file name of calling function not the log.cpp?

Tags: c++

I write a log utils with c++(log.cpp), but when I use it in my other class, I hope to print the line number and file name in calling functions, but unfortunately, it just print the line number and file name of log.cpp. That really confused me.

in Log function, I defined the `prefixFormat` like that, and add `[%s][%d]` format in order to print file name and line name, and set in `strPrefix.Format`

```
strPrefix.Format(prefixFormat, time.wHour, time.wMinute, time.wSecond, stamp, __FILE__, __LINE__, levelNames[loglevel]);
```

```
void CLog::Log(int loglevel, const char *format, ... )
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&m_log_mutex);

  static const char* prefixFormat = "%02.2d:%02.2d:%02.2d T:%" PRIu64 " [%s][%d] %7s: ";
#if !(defined(_DEBUG) || defined(PROFILE))
  if (m_logLevel > LOG_LEVEL_NORMAL ||
     (m_logLevel > LOG_LEVEL_NONE && loglevel >= LOGNOTICE))
#endif
  {
    if (!m_file)
    {
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_log_mutex);
      return;
    }

    struct timeval now;
    gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
    SYSTEMTIME time;
    time.wHour=(now.tv_sec/3600) % 24;
    time.wMinute=(now.tv_sec/60) % 60;
    time.wSecond=now.tv_sec % 60;
    uint64_t stamp = now.tv_usec + now.tv_sec * 1000000;
    CStdString strPrefix, strData;

    strData.reserve(16384);
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, format);
    strData.FormatV(format,va);
    va_end(va);

    if (m_repeatLogLevel == loglevel && m_repeatLine == strData)
    {
      m_repeatCount++;
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_log_mutex);
      return;
    }
    else if (m_repeatCount)
    {
      CStdString strData2;
      strPrefix.Format(prefixFormat, time.wHour, time.wMinute, time.wSecond, stamp, levelNames[m_repeatLogLevel]);

      strData2.Format("Previous line repeats %d times." LINE_ENDING, m_repeatCount);
      fputs(strPrefix.c_str(), m_file);
      fputs(strData2.c_str(), m_file);
      OutputDebugString(strData2);
      m_repeatCount = 0;
    }

    m_repeatLine      = strData;
    m_repeatLogLevel  = loglevel;

    unsigned int length = 0;
    while ( length != strData.length() )
    {
      length = strData.length();
      strData.TrimRight(" ");
      strData.TrimRight('\n');
      strData.TrimRight("\r");
                                     }

    if (!length)
    {
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_log_mutex);
      return;
    }

    OutputDebugString(strData);

    /* fixup newline alignment, number of spaces should equal prefix length */
    strData.Replace("\n", LINE_ENDING"                                            ");
    strData += LINE_ENDING;

    strPrefix.Format(prefixFormat, time.wHour, time.wMinute, time.wSecond, stamp, __FILE__, __LINE__, levelNames[loglevel]);

    fputs(strPrefix.c_str(), m_file);
    fputs(strData.c_str(), m_file);
    //fputs(strPrefix.c_str(), stdout);
    //fputs(strData.c_str(), stdout);
    fflush(m_file);
  }

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_log_mutex);
}
```

but when I call like this `Clog::Log(DEBUG,"XXXXX")` in other classes; I get the file with log.cpp and line number in log.cpp like that, that's really confused me.

```
05:04:49 T:18446744072485586921 [utils/log.cpp][129]   DEBUG: Normal M:16829313 (A:23219955 V:0) P:0 A:6.39 V:-16.83/T:0.20 (0,0,1,1) A:99% V:0% (6.07,6.34)
05:04:49 T:18446744072485607233 [utils/log.cpp][129]   DEBUG: Normal M:16849626 (A:23219955 V:0) P:0 A:6.37 V:-16.85/T:0.20 (0,0,1,1) A:99% V:0% (6.05,6.34)
```

Comment: Why did it really confuse you? In your code `__FILE__` is being used in the file utils/log.cpp and `__LINE__` is being used on line 129. You must remember that the compiler doesn't understand what you want, it just does what you tell it to do, even it that's different from what you meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__LINE__` and `__FILE__` are preprocessor macros and they are not dependent on the code that calls them. A standard way to handle this is to create a wrapper macro around your logging function and let the caller use it instead of calling the logging func directly.

For example:

```
#define Logme(loglevel, format, ... ) Log(__LINE__, __FILE__, loglevel, format, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Inside the `Log` function you'll know that first 2 arguments are line number and file name so you can parse them. Rest of the arguments can be parsed as before.

Comment: also, we need to add ```##`` befor the last flag like that ```#define Logme(loglevel, format, ... ) Log(__LINE__, __FILE__, loglevel, format, 
 ##__VA_ARGS__)```